# Doctrine : get result when array of ids in array

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine, request, dql

i'm developing a website and i'm facing an issue.
My problem is the following one : i have an entity (day) with tags (Tag is also an entity) and i have a list of tags. I want to get the days which have at least all my list of tags in their tags.

Here is an example :

my list of tags : "tag1", "tag2".

my days :

- day1 has tags "tag1", "tag2", "tag3"
- day2 has tag "tag1"

My request should return day1 because all the tags of my list are in the tags of day1.
But i have day1 and day2 in my results :'(

Here is my code :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->leftJoin('d.tags', 't')
            ->where('t IN (:tags)')
            ->setParameter('tags', $tags);


    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: How does your entities and their tables look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by the day and only keeping results that have both tags.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->innerJoin('d.tags', 't')
    ->where('t IN (:tags)')
    ->groupBy('d')
    ->having('count(*) > 1')
    ->setParameter('tags', $tags);
```